# React-Redux, why is action null in a reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Given:

```
//Reducers/ScriptReaderReducers.js
let initialState = {};

const sceneReaderReducers = (state =  initialState, action  => { //eslint-disable-line
  switch (action.type) {
  case ScriptActions.MOVE_NEXT: {
    return {
      ...state, //eslint-disable-line
      currentIndex: action.currentIndex
    };
  }
```

I've mapped this into an app that appears to be otherwise working:

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import SceneReducer from './Logic/Reducers/ScriptReaderReducers.js';

import ScriptSagas from './Logic/Sagas/ScriptSagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// Start history
const history = createHashHistory({});

//Merge Reducers
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
  SceneReducer
});

// Merge middlewares
let middlewares = [
  routerMiddleware(history),
  sagaMiddleware
];

// Development adds logging, must be last
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  middlewares.push( require('redux-logger')({
    // Change this configuration to your liking
    duration: true, collapsed: true
  }) );
}

// Generate store
const store = createStore(connectRouter(history)(rootReducer), 
  {},
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);

console.error(store); //eslint-disable-line

sagaMiddleware.run(ScriptSagas);

// Export all the separate modules
export {
  history,
  store
};
```

On starting up this app in dev, I receive an error message: ScriptReaderReducers.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined.   This appears to be the first test of the switch on action.

I've proven to my satisfaction that actions are being dispatched but I can't seem to get a call stack for the exact timing on this error.

Why would action be null within the Reducers?

Comment: You are missing a paren on the line above.

Comment: Sorry @jmargolisvt, I'm not sure which line you are referring to.  

EDIT:  Wait, I got it.   The signature should be: const sceneReaderReducers = (state =  initialState, action)  => {

Many thanks, I probably would have stared at that for another hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jmargolisvt said, you missed `()` in your code.
Please change line `const sceneReaderReducers = (state =  initialState, action  => {` to `const sceneReaderReducers = ((state =  initialState, action)  => {` and try again.